# Passing variable value to URL

Tags: php, html

I want to pass a `variable` value to an url but the problem is when I first clicked the `search button` the value doesn't appear and when the second clicked is triggered the `variable` value is shown. How can i fix this? I think the fault is when i click the `search button` the page is refreshing. Can someone help me about this?

here's my code:

```
 <div class="form-inline form-padding">
                    <form action="student.php?classid=<?php echo $classid;?>" method="post">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Search by ID or Name">
                        <select name="subject" class="form-control" required>
                            <option value="">Select Subject...</option>                            
                            <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($mysubject)): ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $row['id']?>" <?php if($row['id']==$classid) echo 'selected'; ?>><?php echo $row['subject'];?></option>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                        </select>
                        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search</button>                       
                        <a href="print.php?classid=<?php echo $classid; ?>" target="_blank"><button type="button" name="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-print"></i> Print</button></a>            
                    </form>
                </div>
```

[image]

Comment: which means at first click your `$classid` variable has empty value and only then you are assigning some post values to it

Comment: Why dont you try post request then fetch the data in your php?

Comment: Why don't you use "GET" method for sending value url ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your

```
<form action="student.php?classid=<?php echo $classid;?>" method="post">
```

change it to

```
<form action="student.php" method="post">
```

Comment: I want to pass the value to url why remove the classid?

Comment: you have the a href. if you say <form action="student.php?classid=<?php echo $classid;?>" method="post">, this mean your setting student.php in $classid value which is null.

Comment: the a href tag is the one who passes the value to student.php

Comment: <a href="print.php?classid=<?php echo $classid; ?>" target="_blank"><button type="button" name="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-print"></i> Print</button></a>